# `gnome-screenshot -a` doesn't copy anything to the clipboard on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, gnome, 18.04, gnome-screenshot

For some reason,

```
gnome-screenshot -a
```

allows me to select a rectangle but doesn't seem to copy anything to the clipboard on Ubuntu 18.04. No errors are produced and the command returns `0`.

I assume it has something to do with the move from Unity to GNOME.

Is there an alternative or an update I need?

Comment: Could you expand on "*doesn't seem to work*"? Works fine here. How is it failing for you?

Comment: @pomsky It allows me to select a rectangle but doesn't copy anything to the clipboard. No errors are produced and the command returns 0.

Comment: @pomsky and... that's it, the command is `gnome-screenshot -a -c`

Comment: Check your `~/Pictures` directory to find those "lost" screenshots ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm apparently very bad at reading documentation, the command should be

```
gnome-screenshot -a -c
```

to copy to the clipboard, which is the behavior I wanted.